# How to explicitly use a sequential Collector

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

First of all assert sequential == !parallel

The Java-8 `Stream` interface provides two `collect` methods:

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
              BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
              BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

I need a collector, which collects (or mutably reduces) elements sequentially (**Use case: multiple maps (elements could be maps, recursively) merge, order relevant**). A combiner is not necessary (`Collectors.of` methods also demand a combiner). Is there a better way to somehow do this explicitly?

- using a customized `Collector`?
- similar `of` method without parameter for combiner?
- an existing approach from a lib?

Or **not necessarily a sequential collector** but a parallel approach with strictly left-to-right combiner.

Indeed the correct keyword should be ***Folding Collector***.

Comment: Given an array of maps, whose elements could be maps again, recursively. Expects an uber-map that is the merge result of all those maps. The problem is already solved using recursion. The question is more about if and how to make it a good utility approach, or at all.

Comment: The three bullets at the end of your question describe exactly what collectors are about. So to understand your question, we need to know what you actually think what collectors are…

Comment: It might beyond me to specify this correctly and succinctly. I removed the `SequencialCollector` and the three bullets about a concrete impl.

Comment: @Holger as I understand it, if it runs in parallel, one cannot make any assumption that the combiner will be run sequentially on those partial results, maybe especially when `Characteristics.UNORDERED` is present.

Comment: Since you are the one who decides whether his collector reports the `UNORDERED` characteristic or not, I don’t see the point.

Comment: @Holger I didn't make it clear enough. The answer from Tagir is good enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not the sequential collector, but *folding* collector. This collector could work even with parallel stream performing the upstream operations in parallel, then reducing strictly left-to-right as `forEachOrdered()` does. Unfortunately current Stream API does not support the ordered collectors. I had a [short discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-November/036347.html) in core-libs-dev about the possibility to add special characteristic, which will signal that the collector does not support combining, but there's still no progress in this direction in Java-9.